# Which are the social differences which lead to the variance in the way to address a person?

Tags: historical-linguistics, semantics, cross-linguistic, sociolinguistics

**My question  is: Which are the social differences which lead to the variance in the way to address a person?**

An example of the difference is T-V distinction some languages abolished it while others acquired it.

Greek acquired it 2 and a half centuries ago.
English forsook it in Medieval times or even before.

An other example is the Title.

Greek uses Master(Κύριος) and it commonly means both Master of a house and Mister X.

English altered Master and turned it to Mister so as to address people.

Sir, Herr and the Latin words derived from Senior (Senhor, Signore all derive from Senex which means elder.

The words derived from Dominus are not used in that way (usually).

My question **Why the discrepancy?** What were the differences in society that lead to these differences in languages?

Comment: There are many differences in languages w.r.t. titles and address. Many more differences in other languages than what you mention, in fact. These differences are not caused by any single factor in the cultures; rather, they are simply part of the cultures -- language and culture are not separable, any more than blood and flesh are.

Comment: @jlawler They were indicative examples to illustrate the concept I wanted to be illuminated-explained. They were not intended to be an exhaustive list. I did not ask for a single social factor but the structure and composition of the societies in themselves. How was the society different so as to produce a different language and a different progress.

Comment: Societies do not "produce" languages. Languages are part of society. And all societies are different, in many ways; which ones do you want to correlate, and what do you want to correlate them with?

Comment: @jlawler So I should correct myself and say that social interaction produce languages since it is a part of society; which is the product of such interactions the social rules that bind the social group. At least my Sociologist(In Sociology I and Sociology for Economists told me Society=Social Rules=/=Social Group).

Comment: @jlawler How were the social interactions in these Countries different so as to have a different effect in the Languages and their Progress?